# How to get all years between a range of begin and end date in sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table `evaluations` like this

[image]

I want to convert the `bgn_year` and `end_year` into a eval_year by enumerate all years between the two ranges. the result would look like this:

[image]

I tried with a connect by:

```
select  employee,
     evaluator_type,
     EVALUATOR,
     (bgn_year-1)+level as eval_year
from evaluations
connect by  (bgn_year-1)+level <=end_year
```

But I have to many duplicated rows. I can add a distinct, but I don't think that is the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be something like this (sample data in lines #1 - 7; query you need begins at line #8):

```
SQL> with evaluations (employee, bgn_year, end_year, evaluator_type, evaluator)
  2  as
  3  (select 'A', 2019, 2021, 'POS1', 'X' from dual union all
  4   select 'A', 2018, 2021, 'POS2', 'Y' from dual union all
  5   select 'B', 2019, 2020, 'POS1', 'Z' from dual union all
  6   select 'B', 2020, 2021, 'POS1', 'X' from dual
  7  )
  8  select employee,
  9         --
 10         bgn_year + column_value - 1 as eval_year,
 11         --
 12         evaluator_type,
 13         evaluator
 14  from evaluations cross join
 15       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 16                           connect by level <= end_year - bgn_year + 1
 17                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist));

EMPLOYEE    EVAL_YEAR EVALUATOR_TYPE  EVALUATOR
---------- ---------- --------------- ----------
A                2019 POS1            X
A                2020 POS1            X
A                2021 POS1            X
A                2018 POS2            Y
A                2019 POS2            Y
A                2020 POS2            Y
A                2021 POS2            Y
B                2019 POS1            Z
B                2020 POS1            Z
B                2020 POS1            X
B                2021 POS1            X

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you would do this with a standard SQL recursive query:

```
with cte (employee, bgn_year, end_year, evaluator_type, evaluator, year) as
(
  select employee, bgn_year, end_year, evaluator_type, evaluator, bgn_year from evaluations
  union all
  select employee, bgn_year, end_year, evaluator_type, evaluator, year + 1 from cte
  where year < end_year
)
select employee, year, evaluator_type, evaluator
from cte
order by employee, bgn_year, evaluator_type, evaluator, year;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=588fdf9b08b7d5ac49ad830c5269eb62